# Passing Variable Values of WooCommerce using Pixel Code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been requested by a Marketing company to place a Pixel Code in my WooCommerece checkout page to track conversions and generate reports.

Pixel Code:

```
<!-- Offer Goal Conversion: Cameras -->
```

It's required to replace AMOUNT with the sale amount of my cart and replace SUB_ID with the unique value (Like Order Number/id).

I tried replacing both values with several variables and values Like order_id, $order_id, $subtotal, subtotal but it doesn't seem to read and pass any data to the conversion report.

I need help to identify the correct WooCommerce variables for Cart Subtotal and Order Number that will read and pass data to the conversion report.

My Website is www.Trenddr.com

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**for subtotal:**

1) With global $woocommerce; variable:

```
global $woocommerce;  
$woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
```

// or

```
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal()
```

2) Without global $woocommerce; variable:

```
WC()->cart->subtotal
```

// Or

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()
```

**for the order id:**

```
global $woocommerce, $post;

$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

//to escape # from order id 

$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! if I want to place it in the below pixel code how will it be?

Comment: <!-- Offer Goal Conversion: Drones -->
<iframe src="https://tc.dcmnetwork.com/aff_goal?a=l&goal_id=84&adv_sub=SUB_ID&amount=AMOUNT"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
<!-- // End Offer Goal Conversion -->